# Get-Command & version number

Tags: powershell

I have a need to check to see if a program is installed by looking at an EXE file. Some goofy programs don't behave nicely and put rational info in the registry. I have `Get-Command $path` working, and it allows me to get version info as a property which is also nice. However, I want to do some validation, making sure the file is a valid file. So I tried taking a TXT file and just changing the extension to EXE, and kind of expected `Get-Command` to throw an exception. But no, it works fine and just reports a version number of `0.0.0.0`. When I manually look at the properties of a real EXE and my fake EXE I see that `File version` and `Product version` both exist as properties, but are empty. I'm not casting the version value to `[version]` or anything, so it seems like Windows itself inserts a value of `0.0.0.0` when it's null, which... sucks. Is this something I can actually depend on; that no REAL executable will ever have a value of `0.0.0.0` for Version, and report that as a bad file accordingly? Or is `0.0.0.0` a valid version number that someone might actually use?

Answer (score 3):

`0.0.0.0` is *technically* a valid version number, but I'd say it's quite unlikely that an executable uses it explicitly.

Pragmatically speaking, you can therefore *infer* from the presence of this version number that a given executable *contains no embedded version resource*.

```
$hasVersionResource = (Get-Command some.exe).Version.ToString() -ne '0.0.0.0'
```

However, this aspect is separate from whether a given file is a valid (binary) *executable*, i.e. whether it can actually *run*: binaries do not require this resource in order to execute.